# Resize logos for sm display using Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a strip of 6 sponsor logos being displayed using the Bootstrap 4 grid.

They are displaying very neatly on desktop: similar size all in a row.

However on mobile they all fall into one column with different sizes. (The image files are various sizes)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question: How can I use Bootstrap columns to make them all similar small size sitting perhaps 2 to each row on sm display and smaller?**

Also - should I be using `img-fluid`? Not sure what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `col-sm-6` to each column will do the job. Having 6 units (out of 12) means a column will take up half of the available width in the container:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/animals" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/arch" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/nature" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/people" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/tech" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/animals" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want 2 columns on **all** screens that are smaller than `md` (i.e. on the smallest screens also), then you'd need `col-6` instead of `col-sm-6`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/animals" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/arch" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/nature" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/people" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/tech" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/animals" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-*` **without the infix** is the default i.e. the class that applies from the smallest screens onwards. And if you add classes with an infix such as `col-md-2` etc, you modify the behavior from the infix breakpoint onwards.

Bootstrap grid system reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Very well explained, I used second option with col-6. Thanks.